# Solr: QueryElevationComponent requires StrField uniqueKeyField error

Tags: solr, relevance

I recently installed solr. The example index (found at apache-solr-#.#.#\example\solr) seems to work, and, once copied to my solr home directory, I am able to access it through the admin pages. However when I try to implement a new index by replacing the schema.xml content with (taken from [here](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2010/01/full-text-search-using-solr-lucene-and.html)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <schema name="example" version="1.2">
  <types>
      <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" /> 
      <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" /> 
      <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" /> 
      <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer type="index">
              <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" /> 
              <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" /> 
              <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" /> 
              <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" /> 
              <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt" /> 
          </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" /> 
          <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" /> 
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" /> 
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" /> 
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" /> 
          <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt" /> 
        </analyzer>
      </fieldType>
      </types>
  <fields>
      <field name="fileid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
      <field name="doctext" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" /> 
      <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" /> 
      <field name="datecreated" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" /> 
  </fields>
  <uniqueKey>fileid</uniqueKey> 
  <defaultSearchField>doctext</defaultSearchField> 
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR" /> 
  </schema>
```

I am receiving a configuration error, which seems to suggest that the uniqueKeyField must be implemented with a StrField type (something I find hard to believe is actually the case?)):

**"HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. ... org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: QueryElevationComponent requires the schema to have a uniqueKeyField implemented using StrField at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent.inform(QueryElevationComponent.java:157) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:508) at..."**

My googling has turned up very little to help, so I am hoping there might be someone around here who might have come across this issue and/or have some ideas how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance for any advice, Bea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, at the moment QueryElevationComponent  requires a string unique key. This limitation is [documented in the Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent#elevate.xml).

[Here's the issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1520) in the project JIRA.

Comment: Problem resolved! Thanks for confirming that Mauricio, and for the links. As I won't be needing QueryElevationComponent I have removed it and its handler from my solrconfig.xml file to avoid the problem.

Answer (score -2):

If you are still looking for an answer,

In schema.xml , include the following

```
<fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" /> 
<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NEW" />
```

In elevate.xml, use this ID to map your search term to the best bet result .

```
<elevate>
 <query text="foo bar">
  <doc id="4602376f-9741-407b-896e-645ec3ead457" />
 </query>
</elevate>
```

Here, `4602376f-9741-407b-896e-645ec3ead457` is the value in the "id" field of the best bet document. Wish, Solr allows us to specify any primary key field , say employeeid or productid for specifying in the elevate.xml