# Issue about Schema.xml uniqueKey field

Tags: indexing, solr, solrnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solr: QueryElevationComponent requires StrField uniqueKeyField error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631823/solr-queryelevationcomponent-requires-strfield-uniquekeyfield-error)

I hava configured the schema.xml with different field like

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

when I run solr service it gives me the error like `uniquekey field must be string` then after I change the field type int to string it's working fine

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

but i want to uniquekey in int type.

> HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log
>   files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want
>   solr to continue after configuration errors, change:
>   false in null
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: QueryElevationComponent requires
>   the schema to have a uniqueKeyField implemented using StrField at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent.inform(QueryElevationComponent.java:157)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:508)
>   at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:588) at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Comment: Hi Mauricio Scheffer check now i have add my exact error

Answer (score 5):

Just as the error says, the QueryElevationComponent needs a unique key of type string. [This is documented](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent#elevate.xml).

Answer (score 3):

comment out the section of searchComponent elevator of QueryElevationComponent.  This should disable the elevator feature.  Below is the example

```
<!--
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
</searchComponent>
-->
```

Comment: is this snippet found in **schema.xml** ?

Comment: yes, it is in the schema.xml