# SOLR DIH, error 500

Tags: sql-server, solr

First of all there is a conflict between Solr and MSSQL server in using port 8080.

- So I changed the Tomcat port to the default Solr port 8983.
- Then the problem is when I install the adventure work data base and
  then do all the configuration according to this tutorial:

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/lucene_solr_sql_server

- I then get this error and it does not even open the admin page.

  `HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError> in solr.xml` `------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: QueryElevationComponent requires the schema to have a uniqueKeyField implemented using StrField at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent.inform(QueryElevationComponent.java:158) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:522) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:594) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler' at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:389) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:423) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:459) at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:157) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:563) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373) ... 21 more`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read first lines of log. Your configuration is missing uniqueKey field. How to set read at:

1. [Solr: QueryElevationComponent requires StrField uniqueKeyField error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631823/solr-queryelevationcomponent-requires-strfield-uniquekeyfield-error)
2. [Issue about Schema.xml uniqueKey field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618513/issue-about-schema-xml-uniquekey-field)
3. [SchemaXml - The_Unique_Key_Field](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field)
4. [DataImportHandler - Example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Example:_Indexing_wikipedia)

Comment: add some here, will see what can I help